# Creating a UI object repository for webdriver

Tags: webdriver

For those familiar with automated testing tools, you know that they all have some kind of "object repository" that stores a mapping of UI elements with identifiers. I have found this to be indispensible and I want to duplicate this for webdriver. Has anyone done this ? Any tips ? Google not helping on this one. C# examples if you can, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use [Webinator](http://webinator.codeplex.com/) (which wraps around WebDriver) but the idea is the same - I usually do a static "Map" class like so:

```
public static class CollectionMap
{
    public static Locator
        LocatorTitle           = new Locator(FindBy.Id, "Title"),
        LocatorDescription     = new Locator(FindBy.Id, "Description"),
        LocatorSave            = new Locator(FindBy.Id, "submit"),
        LocatorDelete          = new Locator(FindBy.XPath, "//*[contains(@class,'deleteBox')]/a"),
        LocatorDeleteConfirm   = new Locator(FindBy.Id, "delete-collection-dialogConfirmationLink"),
        LocatorCancel          = new Locator(FindBy.Id, "cancel");
}
```

Used like this:

```
web.Click(CollectionMap.LocatorSave, WaitUntil.AjaxOrPostCompleted());
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am seeking a way to deal with dozens of pages and hundreds of elements.

Comment: Are you looking for a tool that will go to a given page and pull out the elements automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I am creating multiple classes containing mappings to locators. Each class corresponds to a logical grouping of screen elements.

```
public class TopLevel
{
    public const string username = "ctl00_ctl00_Main_Main_txtUsername";
}
```